# Need to read a CSV file and recognize blank lines

Tags: c#, csv

I've read many posts about how to read a CSV file using TextFieldParser and .ReadFields().
I need to read a CSV file up to the first blank line. However, .ReadFields() skips (ignores) blank lines so I don't know when they are encountered in the file.

Is there a way that I can use TextFieldParser and .ReadFields() but also detect when a blank line is encountered in a CSV file?

Comment: Don't think so, `TrimWhiteSpace ` doesn't seem to work either. You may need to have some kind of peekable `Stream` wrapper that can pick up on newlines

Comment: I've never used the CSV parser.  Does it read from files or streams?  If streams, then pump your input through a simple filter (that reads from a stream and writes to another stream that the CSV parser will read from).  In that filter, signal the EOF when you get to a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do this with `TextFieldParser` or not. However, I maintain a library `Sylvan.Data.Csv` which *can* handle this scenario.

Add the nuget package `Sylvan.Data.Csv`. Create a `CsvDataReader` and set the option of `ResultSetMode` to `MultiResult`. This mode will cause the reader to stop any time it detects a change in column count. A blank line will be skipped between result sets.

`CsvDataReader` derives from `System.Data.DbDataReader`, so it can be used in the same way as a `SqlDataReader`. For example, you could use `DataTable.Load(csvDataReader)` to load the results into an ADO.NET data table. Or used a general-purpose data binder to bind it to objects. My `Sylvan.Data` library (currently pre-release nuget package) has such a binder, or the popular `Dapper` library has one as well.

```
using Sylvan.Data.Csv;
...

var csv = CsvDataReader.Create("mydata.csv", new CsvDataReaderOptions { ResultSetMode = ResultSetMode.MultiResult});

while(csv.Read()) {
  for(int i = 0; i < csv.FieldCount; i++) {
    csv.GetString(i);
  }
}

// if you need to process subsequent results:

csv.NextResult(); // returns true if there is a subsequent result set.
```

My library is also the [fastest CSV parser for .NET](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Benchmarks/blob/main/docs/CsvReaderBenchmarks.md); the performance is vastly better than the `TextFieldParser` (VisualBasic), if that's a concern.